# How do I see list of people who follow me AND another person?

Tags: twitter, followers

I'm shocked that it's so hard to find the answer to this question:

How can I see which people following me also follow [some other person]?

Twitter uses this precise relationship to determine who gets to see a tweet I send to someone.   The @user address form goes to the recipient and anyone who follows both of us.

How am I supposed to know who's following both of us?   I can see a list of who is following me but I shouldn't have to go to every person's profile to see if they're also following person X.

Tell me twitter didn't implement a piece of recipient logic that fundamental and powerful, without allowing users to see the list of people their tweet is going to!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It is not exposed in the web UI.

For completeness the first way you mention is:

https://twitter.com/USERNAME/followers_you_follow

e.g.

https://twitter.com/xsteenbrugge/followers_you_follow

Where you then have to look for "Follows you" badges in the displayed list.

The second way is using the intersection of API calls to this endpoint.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids.html

Where in the first call `user_id` is your user id and in the second it's the other user's id.